# why is my redux state null when accessing in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So in my application I have a profile page which I have checked successfully sets the redux state with the profile data after dispatching when the page is loaded, I then try to access this state in another component within my app after a redirect (not a browser refresh) and using the useSelector hook but it tells me that the redux data in null and I cannot figure out why have I done something wrong in my reducers, component or store? I am just using react router dom navigation to redirect from profile page where redux state is set, to the other component when the nav button is clicked

profileSlicer:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchProfileByUsername = createAsyncThunk("profile/fetchByUsername", async (username) => {
    console.log("fetching by username in redux ")
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3002/userProfile', {
        params: {
            username: username
        }
    });
    return response.data;
});

export const fetchProfileByQrId = createAsyncThunk("profile/fetchByQrId", async (qr_id) => {
    console.log("fetching by qr_id in redux ")
    //const response = await axios.get('https://lovinglegacy.onrender.com/getProfile', {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3002/getProfile', {
    params: {
            qr_id: qr_id
        }
    });
    return response.data;
});

const profileSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'profile',
    initialState: {
        isLoading: false,
        data: null,
        error: false,
    },
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchProfileByUsername.pending, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = true;
            })
            .addCase(fetchProfileByUsername.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false;
                state.data = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(fetchProfileByUsername.rejected, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = false;
                state.error = true;
            })
            .addCase(fetchProfileByQrId.pending, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = true;
            })
            .addCase(fetchProfileByQrId.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false;
                state.data = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(fetchProfileByQrId.rejected, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = false;
                state.error = true;
            });
    }
});

export default profileSlice.reducer;
```

store:

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import profileReducer from '../redux/ProfileSlicer';

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        profile: profileReducer,
    }
})
```

Component trying to access redux state in after it has been set:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import CreateNewMedallionProfile from "../../CreateMedallionProfile";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ProfileDetails = () => {
    const profileData = useSelector(state => state.profile.data);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Profile data in profile details ", profileData);
    }, [profileData]); // Add profileData to dependency array to listen for changes

    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log("clicked profile data ", profileData);
    }

    // Render the component only if profileData exists
    if (!profileData) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
            <CreateNewMedallionProfile />
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProfileDetails;
```

Snippet from where redux state is set component:

```
const profileData  = useSelector(state => state.profile.data);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log("profile data from redux store = ", profileData);

 

  useEffect(() => {
    const username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    const qr_id = localStorage.getItem('qr_id');
    if(username) {
      console.log("username from local storage ")
      dispatch(fetchProfileByUsername(username));
      
    }
    else if(qr_id) {
      console.log("qr_id from local storage");
      dispatch(fetchProfileByQrId(qr_id));
    }
    // Dispatch action to fetch profile data only on page refresh
    
  }, [])

  // Effect to make GET request to sever function when profileData changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if(profileData) {
      // Extract the username from profileData
      const username = profileData.username;
      console.log("in here");
    

    // make a GET request to the server-side function
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/userProfile`, {
          params : {
            username: username
          }
        });
        console.log("Response from server: ", response.data);
        setMedallionProfile(response.data.medallionProfile); // store fetched data in the state
        // Handle the response data as needed here 
      } catch(error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data: ', error);
        // Rest of handling the error show error msg client side??
        }
      };
    fetchData() // Call the fetchData function
    }
  }, [profileData])   // dependancy to run the effect when ever profile data changes
```

Comment: So the state is set... and how exactly are you getting to the other component, `ProfileDetails`? Please [edit] to clarify the issue, the exact reproduction steps, and a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

Comment: @DrewReese I am just using react router dom navigation to redirect from profile page where redux state is set, to the other component when the nav button is clicked, that's why i don't understand why the redux state isn't set

Comment: Can you show that navigation as part of a complete [mcve]?